# How to update in PostgreSQL a table with millions records?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I need to update 9 columns of a table t1 with nearly 10 millions rows in Postgres. The query I am applying is:

```
update t1 
set 
  class = t2.class,
  direction = t2.direction,
  bt = t2.bt,
  rf = t2.rf,
  private = t2.private,
  cat = t2.cat,
  ref = t2.ref,
  to_ref = t2.to_ref, 
  public = t2.public
from table2 t2 
where  t2.link_id = t1.link_id
```

Both t1 and table2 have nearly 10 millions rows. The problem is that query takes way too long (days and still no finished). Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any other possible way to make it work?

link_id character varying in both tables and it is the PRIMARY KEY of table2. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please post the `EXPLAIN` output for the query.

Comment: `create index on t1 ( link_id);` Maybe it could even be unique...

Comment: @ Learenz Albe: there is  nothing at the EXPLAIN as the query is still running

Comment: @joop: I read somewhere that indexing in UPDATE makes things even worst. But I guess I have nothing to lose if I try it. Thanks.

Comment: @CorneliaS : That depends on the relative size of the affected set. If it fits in core, a hash-method *can* be used, and will probably be fastest. Another factor is avoiding idempotent updates and multiple updates. It all depends on your data.

Comment: Did you check if there is a lock of any kind? Updating a row which is included in another update or select may cause statement to wait indefinitely.

Comment: @Uwe Allner  how can i check such lock?

Comment: Just a suggestion: `vacuum analyze full t1;` (of course it is impossible if your update query still running) Sometime the defragmentation helps. About locks: [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-locks.html) and [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring)

Comment: Lots of missing information. While the query is running post Postgresql version and the tables' psql `\d` output.

Comment: For example you can find locks via the server state tool in pgAdmin.

Comment: Here is what 'EXPLAIN' gives me when trying to update the (tables are renamed).    'Update on routing  (cost=601733.63..1795621.98 rows=9712517 width=212)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=601733.63..1795621.98 rows=9712517 width=212)
        Hash Cond: (routing.id = t2.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on routing  (cost=0.00..362998.87 rows=9712687 width=198)
        ->  Hash  (cost=423417.17..423417.17 rows=9712517 width=18)
              ->  Seq Scan on test t2  (cost=0.00..423417.17 rows=9712517 width=18)' It seems that it is a vebr ending query. I checked for locks from server status and it seems ok.